# <c:if> statement in jsp doesn't work properly

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have he statement in JSP as below:

```
     <% String fname = "abcd" %>

        <c:if test="${not empty fname}">
       <% out.println("not empty"+fname); %>
        </c:if> 

    <c:if test="${empty fname}">
    <% out.println(" empty"+fname); %>
    </c:if>
```

in the page it displays - emptyabcd - > means it goes to the second if (not empty) even though, fname has values. any idea why ?

Comment: In addition to skaffman's answer, use `<c:out>` instead of the `<% out.println() %>` mess. E.g. `not empty <c:out value="${fname}" />` and `empty <c:out value="${fname}" />`. You can even replace it by just `${fname}` if it doesn't contain user-controlled data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSTL doesn't read page variables defined in scriptlets - the two styles are separate and don't work well together.

Instead of

```
<% String fname = "abcd" %>
```

you need something like:

```
<c:set var="fname" value="abcd"/>
```

If you *must* use scriptlets, then you need to add the variable to the page context before JSTL can read it:

```
<% 
   pageContext.setAttribute("fname", "abcd");
%>
```

Comment: actually I need to get fname from the session.                     String lname = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute((EnterpriseConstants.USER_LAST_NAME));

Answer (score 0):

actually I need to get fname from the session.
I'm doing like this-
              <%String fname =(String)request.getSession().getAttribute            ((EnterpriseConstants.USER_FIRST_NAME));%>

```
      <c:set var = "fname" value = "<%=request.getSession().getAttribute ((EnterpriseConstants.USER_FIRST_NAME))%>";/>
```

the fname i need to display in the page. if I the first name as null or spaces that I get from session, user can enter it or it will be protected. So I need to check for that before I display the page.

```
             <c:if test="${not empty fname}">
<html:text name="form1" property="firstName" styleClass="formContent" value="<%=fname.toUpperCase()%>" style = "background:#C8C8C8"  readonly="true"  maxlength="15" size="10"/>            
</c:if>     
     <c:if test="${empty fname}">           
<html:text name="form1" property="firstName"   
      styleClass="formContent"  maxlength="15" size="10"/>
</c:if>
```

question -
1) do i need to get fname to a string and then do a  ?  If I just do a  var = "fname", when i try to use this variable in  statement, it gives me error. so I had to get fname into a String fname first. now it is working. any other way ??